# Is there a way to get only the user account names in windows?

Tags: python, windows

I want to just get the user names. I don't really understand how to cut the strings

```
import subprocess<br/>
users=subprocess.getoutput('net user')<br/>
print(users) <br/><br/>
```

This is the output:

```
User accounts for xxxxxxxxxx

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
user1                    userA            admin

The command completed successfully.
```

I just want a list of all the user accounts. How do I make that happen?

Comment: The preferred way would be to use the API instead of unreliably parsing command line output. A big problem is what codepage the "net.exe" command uses for its output. You can figure it out, but it's an undocumented hackfest. Just call the wide-character API [`NetUserEnum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/nf-lmaccess-netuserenum) with level 0 (just names).

Comment: For example, if PyWin32 is installed: `import win32net;` `users = sorted(u['name'] for u in win32net.NetUserEnum(None, 0)[0])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the piece of data you want starts from the fifth line (index 4) of the output generated by net users. The very last line must be ignored as well.
Usernames are stored in first parts of all other lines when they are split by a space.

```
import subprocess users=subprocess.getoutput('net user')

for l in users.splitlines()[4:-1]:
    s = l.split(' ')[0]
    print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the `/etc/passwd` file:

```
import subprocess
users_file = subprocess.getoutput("cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd")
# Split the output on newline character and remove the lines with comments starting with #
users = [x for x in users.split("\n") if "#" not in x]
```

Output:

```
# ['nobody',
#  'root',
#  'daemon',
#  ...
#  ...
# '_reportmemoryexception',
# '_driverkit']
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am looking for one that would work in Windows